# Cannot find route to 'js' within 'Public' folder...using'views'?

Tags: javascript, view, ejs, public

I have a structure similar to the following:

```
--Public
 --js
  --main.js
--Views
 --Pages
  --about.ejs
 --Partials 
  --head.ejs
  --header.ejs
  --footer.ejs
--Server.js
```

In my HTML (.ejs) page (about.ejs) I have the path to use the 'main.js' within the 'Public' folder defined as

```
    ...
    <script src="/public/js/main.js"></script>
    ...
```

However my tests indicate this is failing.  I simply attempt to change the 'innerHTML' of a paragraph on the 'about.ejs' page within the 'main.js' as the test...since nothing happens I assume the HTML (.ejs) page is not able to find the javascript file within the 'Public' folder. Any help appreciated greatly...this is immensely frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use NodeJs. Probably, you need to serve static files.

[Expressjs's serving static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Yes sir that is correct I am using Node.js.  I have  added app.use(express.static('public'))" as per the link 
supplied however I am seeing no change.  I have another event handler embedded in my HTML (ejs) page for the same
button...is it possible that they interfere with each other?  It seems I can only embed Javascript within the 
HTML (ejs) page itself for usage, which is obviously not desirable.  Is there a tutorial link someplace that 
indicates how to use public folders with .ejs files?

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: Does the script call possibly need to be in the 'partial' .ejs page known as 'head.ejs'...?  Since that is the first partial page called on my HTML (ejs) page...I have the link to .css bootstrap in there already...

Comment: If you put app.use(express.static('Public')) , src must be like "/js/main.js".

Comment: I think I have it now...I used "app.use("/public, express.static('public'))" and removed some old legacy code that might have been causing issue...I also include the 'public' in 'src'.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your project structure, your `Public` directory is in titlecase

Try:

```
<script src="/Public/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: No sir I just typed it that way here...a lowercase 'public' is used in my script call and the actual folder name.  Thank you.